# Create a datatable on the basis of a column of another Datatable Groupby using linq?

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a datatable in which data is something like this, in which a feature can have multiple Storyid and different person assigned to it.4th row of featureid of the 1st image is 26450 and not 26540) my mistake

[image]

i want another datatable in which same feature will tell the stories id and hrs(sum) and assigned to like shown in the image

[image]

Comment: Are the last 2 rows in your first table supposed to have the same value for `Featureid`? (4 and 5 are transposed)

Comment: Any try from your side?

Comment: @StephenMuecke can be diffrent (all rows can be diffrent)

Comment: I think you misunderstood. The 3rd row has a value of `26450` and the 4th row has a value of `26540` - yet you want then to be grouped in the 2nd table. Is that just a typo and should they both have a value of `25450`

Comment: not a typo i want them to be group by on the basis of Feature id

Comment: So therefore how could your 2nd table have a row containing "sam" and "sonia" when they have different values for `Featureid`?

Comment: because sam and sonia has worked on same featureid 26450

Comment: Look very very carefully at the data in your first table `26450` is not the same as `26540`!

Comment: sorry by mistake it's 26450 in the 4th column as well

Comment: @StephenMuecke got it ?

Comment: Yep - I assumed it was a typo :)

Answer (score 2):

Let `myTable` be your current table, then you can try with the following code to get the result that you are looking:

```
var result = myTable.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x=> x["Featureid"])
                                   .Select(item => new 
                                   {
                                       Feature = item.Key, 
                                       AssignedTo = string.Join(",", item.Select(a=>a["AssignedTo"])),
                                       Stories = string.Join(",", item.Select(s=>s["storyid"])),
                                       CompletedHrs= item.Sum(y=>y["CompletedHrs"]))
                                    });
```

Comment: I think you mean `item.Select(s=>s.storyid)`

Comment: getting error Featureid does not exist in current context

Comment: @AkhilJain: I have made some updates, please check them

Comment: could u pls tell me how to make put the Query data(result) to a datatable ?? @un-lucky

Comment: @AkhilJain: Try : `result.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165456/discussion-between-un-lucky-and-akhil-jain).

Answer (score 0):

Let Your Table Name is  **FeatureAssigned**

,then you can try the following code .It will give you your expected output

```
var result = db.FeatureAssigned
      // If you have a filter add the .Where() here ...
      .GroupBy(e => e.Featureid)
      .ToList()
      // Because the ToList(), this select projection is not done in the DB
      .Select(eg => new 
       {
          Feature= eg.Key,
          AssignedTo = string.Join(",", eg.Select(b=>b.AssignedTo )),
          Stories = string.Join(",", eg.Select(c=>c.storyid)),
          CompletedHrs= eg.Sum(z=>z.CompletedHrs)
       });
```

Comment: This is the same as the answer added 15 minutes ago!

Comment: what is db ? @Farhan